# How to add multiple parameters to a store procedure in MVC Entity framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am Using VS2012 with MVC4 and EntityFramework.

I need a ***suggestion*** on how to add multiple parameters to a store procedure in a well manner. I use the code below, but I think it's not a good way of writing code, if anyone knows a better way please share it.

if my store procedure parameter are more than 10 then it does not look good.

***My ActionMethod***

```
    public ActionResult SaveVoucher(Voucher items)
    {

        List<MVC_GetMaxCouponMasterByDept_Result> LastCouponId = db.MVC_GetMaxCouponMasterByDept(
            items.vDeptCode,
            items.vComp,
            items.vFinYear,
            items.vLoc,
            items.CostCenter
            ).ToList<MVC_GetMaxCouponMasterByDept_Result>();

        return View();
    }
```

Comment: it's a good way but try to not use string literals, use a constants

Comment: here its just example ..yes i will use constants.., but here i want to know how to add prarameters to store procedure by better way

Comment: Why do you think that this is not a better way?

Answer (score -1):

The SP code could should be in a helper class which take in the params and not directly in you ActionMethod, this way its reusable.

**PS this is not complete**, I am not going to write it all for you but this should help you.

As of the nature of this question the scope can keep getting bigger and bigger, ie there are a million ways to refactor this more.... so I suggestion you read more up on design patterns as they will help you on your quest.

```
public ActionResult SaveVoucher(Voucher items)
{
    SpHelper spHelper = new SpHelper();
    var data  = spHelper.GetMaxCouponMasterByDept(item.vDeptCode);
    return View(data);
}


//this is in its own class file..
public class SpHelper
{
     private DbContext db = new DbContext()
     public List<MVC_GetMaxCouponMasterByDept_Result> GetMaxCouponMasterByDept(string vDeptCode)
     {
         var data = db.MVC_GetMaxCouponMasterByDept(
                    vDeptCode,"CCL", "2015-2016",
                  "Mumbai","10001554"
                  ).ToList();
          return data;
     }

     //... other helpful Sp you have created
}
```

Comment: @MegaTron yeah but i was going for a dependency injection approach but it way out of scope for this...which is why i updated... suggesting he look up design patterns

Comment: @MegaTron how? is it not better. Please explain that comment. its like a million time better if you understand the SOLID principles... I didn't want to move to fast!... as otherwise I would have to write an entire class lib for him. I'm interested as to where your answer is.

Comment: @MegaTron with your static instance please explain the life cycle of the context?

Comment: Calm down. Read about Utility pattern.
If that code will use only in one place there is not make sense to create a helper class. In other case when the code should be reusable then your helper class is completely wrong.
I suppose that all parameters that passing to procedure should not be statis and always should change. In this case you hardcode the values of parameters in common class. It's mean that procedure will be run with always the same value like "Mumbai","10001554" ect. Do you think is it correct to hardcode value of parameters? What about reusable?

Comment: @MegaTron please re-read what i said. (i think you missed the part in bold) I still haven't seen your answer.. nor did you explain how you were handling life cycles. Politeness is normally earned...leading from saying "just other way but not better" is like me say you just trying to be polite and professional. I was stating my case as to why i don't think its the same, and was just asking how you came to that conclusion when you hadn't contributed anything.